# Evento ao pressionar o toque no botao

Tags: javascript, jquery

Teria alguma forma de detectar o toque pressionado em um botão? O código funciona normal no *desktop*, mas quando vou testar no *mobile* não aciona.

Usar o *JqueryMobile* não é uma opção.

```js
var timeout = 0;

$('button').mousedown(function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(menu_toggle, 2000);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});

function menu_toggle() {
  alert('ok');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>pressionar</button>
```

Comment: Por quê não usa o evento `click`?

Comment: Para mobile/touchscreen tem [um conjunto específico de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events): `touchstart`, `touchend`, `touchmove`, `touchcancel`.

Comment: Não é só clicar, preciso pressionar por alguns segundos.

Comment: Editei minha resposta e testei no meu mobile e funciona bem.

Answer (score 2):

> Você precisará de temporizadores, defina um quando o mouse estiver pressionado, limpe-o quando o mouse for liberado.

```js
$( "#target" ).on({
mousedown: function() {
    $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function() {
          foo();
    }, 4000));
},
mouseup: function() {
    clearTimeout( $(this).data('timer') );
}
});


function foo() {
//alert('Diego Vieira, obrigado por me pressionar por 4 segundos !')
 console.log('Diego Vieira, obrigado por me pressionar por 4 segundos !')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="target">Diego Vieira, pressione-me por 4 segundos</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta:

```
$('button').on('click touchstart', function() {
```

Comment: A ideia é pressionar o botão durante alguns segundos. Com o click não da pq o evento é acionado na hora.

Comment: Esse timeout é realmente necessário? Eu não sei o que quer fazer exatamente, é claro, mas as vezes a resposta pode estar em outra coisa. Talvez chame essa função menu_toggle em algum outro evento.. Se for pegar algo de um servidor pode ser o evento de sucesso ou erro. Qual é o objetivo?

Comment: O objetivo é chamar a função menu_toggle quando pressionar o dedo no botão durante 2 segundos.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim, então:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeout = 0;

$('button').mousedown(function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(menu_toggle, 2000);
});

function menu_toggle() {
  alert('ok');
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Pode usar o evento click, touchstart...

Answer (score 0):

Tente dessa forma, pode te ajudar a resolver o problema, sem dependência de libs.
Nesse script foi mantido sua ideia inicial como iria funcionar, porem escrito de outra forma.

Dois ouvintes de eventos são adicionados ao botão, um que executa a função quando o botão é pressionado '`mousedown`' e outra quando o botão não está mais sendo acionado pelo usuário '`mouseup`'. Espero que ajude.

```
const button =  document.querySelector('#btn');

let timeout = 0;

const menu_toggle = function() {
  alert('ok');
};

button.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
  timeout = setTimeout(menu_toggle, 2000);
}, false);

button.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente nenhuma nas respostas acabaram funcionando no *mobile*.

A única coisa que resolveu foi utilizar o *plugin* *Jquery* *Finger*, que é feito especialmente para isso.

Vou deixar o *link* caso alguém passe por esse mesmo problema:

https://ngryman.sh/jquery.finger/